# Ubuntu: SQL time is not the same as current OS timezone

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, database, ubuntu-16.04

Hey I tried to change my ubuntu timezone to UTC+2 and I did it.
The timezone before was America/New-York and as I saw in forums SQL time must be the same as OS time, But nope. 
When UTC+2 is 16:45 the SQL shows NY time (09:45) 
Help is highly appreciated 
 Thank you very much!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  How have you configured the RDBMS?  *(Different RDBMS can be configured differently)*  What exact SQL are you using?  *(Different RDBMS have differing support for timezones and how they expose that.)*

Comment: @MatBailie I am using the SQL mysql-server package.
Probably uploaded by oracle. 
I didn't touch anything, as said help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `What exact SQL are you using? (Different RDBMS have differing support for timezones and how they expose that.)`  What exactly are you typing to get the results you have shown?

Comment: You may wish to read this and related documents : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: restart your mysql server and it will be same as your OS.

Answer (score 1):

It might be using cached timezone data. If you change the operating system timezone and have not restart the mysql service, it may use the previous timezone. Restart mysqld and run `SELECT NOW();` to check.

```
sudo service mysql restart
```